# Return list of files recursively in Go, including root directory

Tags: go

Wonder if there is a quick way to get a list of files in a root directory that includes the root directory itself.

```
 sourceDir, err := os.Open(startPath)
 if err != nil {
         return err
 }
 defer sourceDir.Close()

 files, err := sourceDir.Readdir(0)
```

This only all the files/subdirectorys in "startPath" not "startPath" itself. I have to manually append the fileInfo of startPath to the files manually. Is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 4):

This is what [`filepath.Walk`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk) is for.

This will recursively print out every filename:

```
filepath.Walk(startPath, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    fmt.Println(path)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("ERROR:", err)
    }
    return nil
})
```